# What do we mean by " A directory cannot be written on by unprivileged programs" in UNIX?

Tags: unix, operating-system

While Reading a Research paper- **The UNIX Time- Sharing System by Dennis M. Ritchie and Ken Thompson**, I stuck at a line which says that

> "A directory behaves exactly like an ordinary file except that it
>   cannot be written on by unprivileged programs, so that the system
>   controls the contents of directories. However, anyone with appropriate
>   permission may read a directory just like any other file."

Does it mean that, no files can be stored or can be renamed in directory by unprivileged programs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it mean that, no files can be stored or can be renamed in directory by unprivileged programs?

It means the CONTENTS of a directory file can only be modified through system services.